# Combine text in dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['AC1', 'AC2', 'AC3', 'AC4', 'AC5'], 
                   'col2': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 
                   'col3': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'FGH', 'IJK', 'LMN']})
```

I want to comnbine text of 'col3' if values in 'col2' are duplicated. The result should be like this:

```
    col1  col2       col3
0   AC1    A      ABC, IJK
1   AC2    B      DEF, FGH
2   AC3    B      DEF, FGH
3   AC4    A      ABC, IJK
4   AC5    C      LMN
```

I start this excercise by finding duplicated values in this dataframe:

```
col2 = df['col2']
df1 = df[col2.isin(col2[col2.duplicated()])]
```

Any suggestion what I should do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
a = df.groupby('col2').apply(lambda group: ','.join(group['col3']))
df['col3'] = df['col2'].map(a)
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
   col1     col2    col3
0   AC1     A   ABC,IJK
1   AC2     B   DEF,FGH
2   AC3     B   DEF,FGH
3   AC4     A   ABC,IJK
4   AC5     C   LMN
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to leverage [the groupby and apply functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) in Pandas

```
df.groupby('col2').apply(lambda group: ','.join(group['col3']))
```

Comment: don't forget to close your parenthesis at the end. You may want to add a comma in group: ', '.join... to answer the OP in full according to col3

Comment: great - check your answer it's a bit off from the OPs request (see number of rows in your result vs his/her result)

Comment: k it's comma join

Comment: I think `map` was missing. I have added it in my answer. Up-voted your answer as well.

Comment: @moys Voted yours, mine requires more steps to clean up the index : p